# vertically aligning elements in a div

Tags: css

I have these chech boxes in my div But they all are appearing in a 2 lines .

I want to make them vertically , so that only one checkbox will appear in one line and second chek box appear on 2nd line and so on ..

```
                <g:CheckBox > Article </g:CheckBox>
                <g:CheckBox > Form1 </g:CheckBox>
                <g:CheckBox > Payroll </g:CheckBox>
                <g:CheckBox > TAX </g:CheckBox>
                <g:CheckBox > Import/Export </g:CheckBox>
                <g:CheckBox > Business Consent Form </g:CheckBox>
                <g:CheckBox > HST </g:CheckBox>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the HTML Code, you can put this:

```
input {display: block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

For each textbox element, I'd use `clear:both;` which means nothing to the right or to the left, therefore skip line. Clear is sort of the opposite of `float`.

Comment: There's nothing to clear since they aren't floated in the first place. Inputs are inline elements per default, so `display: inline` should be `display: block;`